# How to remove all instances inside a list where a contained list does not contain all values given? help please

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

So I am trying to set up a searching system, for which I need to go through each 'book' in a list and remove each one that does not match the given 'genres'. each book contains a list of genre ID's.

I used this and I am sure it used to work but maybe it was my imagination...

```
books.RemoveAll(i => i.genres != null && !genres.All(x => i.genres.Any(y => x == y)));
```

does anyone know how to implament this feature?

Thank you!

Comment: What does "does not match the given genres" mean? Give some examples of books with genres, and a list of genres they do/do not match

Comment: are you saying that books have many genres, and you only want to return those that have all their genres in the `genres` list?

Comment: Also, it's completely allowed to use readable names as variables in Linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're saying that a book has many genres, and you want to filter a list of books based on a list of genres such that all books in the list have all their genres in the genre list.

This answer is also assuming that the `Genre` class implements `IComparable<Genre>`. In this example `genres` is a `List<string>`:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title;
    public List<string> Genres;
}
```

Then for sample data, we can create a list of books and a list of genres:

```
var genres = new List<string> {"Horror", "Action", "Adventure"};

var books = new List<Book>
{
    new Book {Title = "The Shining", Genres = new List<string> {"Horror", "Adventure"}},
    new Book {Title = "Sahara", Genres = new List<string> {"Action", "Adventure"}},
    new Book {Title = "The Odds", Genres = new List<string> {"Action", "Comedy"}}
};
```

If that's the case, this should do the trick:

```
books.RemoveAll(book =>
    book.Genres != null &&
    book.Genres.Any(genre => !genres.Contains(genre)));

// The last book is removed from the list, because 'genres' doesn't contain "Comedy"
```

Comment: I have 3 books, one which has 3 genres {'1','2','3'} (i actually save them as id's but that's probably not important), another book that only has the '2' genre, and the last one has mo genres.
when i try to remove all the books that do not contain gennre '2' using what you wrote, it only removed the first book and left the other two...

Comment: oh i fixed it. i replaced book.Genres.Any(genre => !genres.Contains(genre))); with genres.Any(genre => !book.Genres.Contains(genre)));

Thank you very much!

Comment: It would be helpful if you updated your question with sample code that reproduces the problem. I'm just guessing what you're data structures look like. I'm also not sure what exactly you're trying to do, so including sample input and expected output would be helpful also.

Comment: Yes sorry I'm new to stack overflow and i'm not quite familiar of proper posting etiquette, though now my problem was solved, thank you! :)